# Отправка информации System.IO.FileInfo по почте

Tags: c#

Как информацию, что выводится в консоль `Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, sLen);` сделать выводом в тело письма?

```
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.Root;
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
        {
            string sLen = fi.Length.ToString();
            if (fi.Length >= (1 << 30))
                sLen = string.Format("{0}Gb", fi.Length >> 30);
            else
                if (fi.Length >= (1 << 20))
                    sLen = string.Format("{0}Mb", fi.Length >> 20);
                else
                    if (fi.Length >= (1 << 10))
                        sLen = string.Format("{0}Kb", fi.Length >> 10);


            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, sLen);

            string message = ???;

        }

    try
  { 
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailto));
    mail.Subject = caption;
    mail.Body = message;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachFile))
      mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachFile));
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); 
    client.Host = smtpServer; 
    client.Port = 587; 
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Split('@')[0], password);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Send(mail);
    mail.Dispose();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception("Mail.Send: " + e.Message);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//using System.IO;    
//using System.Text;
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
var fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var fi in fileNames)        
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, ToPrint(fi.Length));
}
var message = sb.ToString();
```

И выносим код в метод:

```
static string ToPrint(long length)
{
    var sLen = length.ToString();
    if (length >= (1 << 30))
        sLen = string.Format("{0}Gb", length >> 30);
    else if (length >= (1 << 20))
        sLen = string.Format("{0}Mb", length >> 20);
    else if (length >= (1 << 10))
        sLen = string.Format("{0}Kb", length >> 10);
    return sLen;
}
```

Comment: Полностью работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Форматированный вывод можно осуществлять не только в консоль:

```
message +=  string.Format("{0}: {1}: {2}\r\n", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, sLen);
```

Саму переменную объявите вне цикла:

```
string message = "";
...
foreach(...)
```

Comment: На моем начальном этапе изучения, это очень важная и полезная информация. Спасибо.

Comment: Да вы чего *такое* начинающему-то советуете! `message +=`, да еще и в цикле - это ж привет тормозам и лагам...

Comment: @PavelMayorov может, преподадите урок начинающему, например, создайте тест, где можно будет узнать на каком миллионе файлов начнутся тормоза и как это будет нездорово

Comment: @FLCL, В интернете про это написано достаточно. Можно поискать по ключевым словам "c# string stringbuilder". Не вижу смысла повторять уже сказанное своими словами.